# discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

```
const role = Discord.guildMember.roles.find(role => role.name === 'test');
message.author.guildMember.roles.add(role);
```

My Code İs This But I get A Error Says ;

TypeError: member.addRole is not a function

It Shows This Line ;

```
const role = Discord.guildMember.roles.find(role => role.name === 'test');
```

is broken but ı can't figure out what is the problem
discord.js v12

Answer (score 0):

You try to find a role off the user, you could try to use this to find the role in the guild that the message was sent in.

```
let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

For discord v12 you need use `....roles.cache.find(` and `message.author` has no property `member` or `guildMember`, [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) its a [user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object.

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'test');
if(role) message.member.roles.add(role);
```